# Terminal based application for downloading torrent

Tags: command-line, bittorrent, torrent-client

How can I download torrent file from websites using command line?
I've done it using Bittorrent and I want to know that is it possible to download torrent using terminal?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `aria2` to download torrent.

```
sudo apt install aria2
```

Then to use it:

```
aria2c http://example.org/mylinux.torrent
aria2c 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:248D0A1CD08284299DE78D5C1ED359BB46717D8C'
```

Comment: This means you need to know the torrent id. https://flexget.com/Install lets you create a script based on name, season, series etc to scrape torrent.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using rTorrent. It is installable from the repositories and is very lightweight and CLI only.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/RTorrent Is an instruction manual.

To download the .torrent files I would recommend wget by calling "wget "http://link.to/torrent"".